# Reading '&' value from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I face problem while reading the following value from xml file using C#

```
xml data contains <Address>ASST. manager, MAINTANANCE & dept  </Address>
```

Comment: Hello. Please proved some sample code, examples of what you have tries and any exceptions or logs generated. Cheers.

Comment: @Nico, something tells me that the problem is not within the code, but between the specs. He receives an error because the parser encountered a special character. The `&` should be replaced with `&amp;`.

Comment: I receive error: " '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 13636, position 34. "

I understand that the problem is  reading the '&' But i need to read it, how?

Comment: If you have access to the generation of the XML, save all the elements inside a `CDATA`: `<Address><![CDATA[ASST. manager, MAINTANANCE & dept]]></Address>`. You will not be able to use the `&` as plain text otherwise.

Comment: I have no permission in  generation of the XML, I want to read only- AndreiV

Comment: Well, that's not a valid XML. The only way I can think of for reading it is to implement your own XML parser. I don't think you want that...  If you know the supplier of the XML, ask them to use `CDATA` inside all elements. If not, try to open the file as a text file and either replace special characters or add `CDATA` elements yourself.

Comment: Instead of wrapping the text in `CDATA` you could replace the `&` with `&amp;`. As it is it's invalid XML.

Comment: @HansKesting, that's actually what I would do. It the most simple solution. I suggested `CDATA` as there might be other special characters as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters

Comment: Another problem: My data is as Designation="OFFICER GRADE G - II", but when xml is generated the xml file  contains some illegal character and looks like <Designation>OFFICER GRADE b<some illegal char> II</Designation>
This xml create a problem in the time of reading the xml file by C#